Fixing a complicated class w/union + struct
I have a somewhat complex class that compiles with Visual Studio 2019 with no issues.  I'm trying to compile it now in GCC.  It gives me an error because I'm using a class within an anonymous union, like so:
class Vertex
{
    union
    {
        Vector mPos;
        struct
        {
            float mX;
            float mY;
            float mZ;
        };
    };

    union
    {
        struct
        {
            unsigned int    mColor;

            union // Line 250
            {
                Point mUV;
                struct
                {
                    float mU;
                    float mV;
                };
            };
        };
        Vector mNormal; // Tacked on so we can use this as a POS/NORMAL pair if we don't need UV+Color
    };
};

I receive the following error:
error: member ‘Vertex::<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct>::<unnamed union> Vertex::<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct>::<anonymous>’ with constructor not allowed in anonymous aggregate
  250 |                         union
      |                         ^~~~~

(Line 250 is indicated with the comment, the union line right before Point mUV).
I'm pretty sure the issue is because my Point class has a bunch of constructors (including a blank one with no parameters), but I can't figure out what to do to it to make it usable within this union.
What can I do?

Anonymous structs (struct { /* whatever */ }; are a Microsoft thing. They're not C++.

Also Point and Vector have constructors. Then, the system cannot resolve which of these two must be used. Then using objects with constructors in unions can be the cause of the problem

@PeteBecker But I have other anonymous structs that it doesn't complain about.  This seems to be an issue of having union -> struct -> constructor (in fact, I've been using anonymous structs since the 90s, on various systems) In other places I have comparable union/structures with Point and Vector that do not give me grief.  It seems to be only this configuration.

Have you tried giving names to all of the anonymous items? Also, it may make sense for a Vector to share memory with 3 floats for XYZ, but does it make sense for a Vector to share memory with an int color and 2 floats for UV?

What g++ version (and -std= argument to set C++ version) are you using?  Prior to C++14, unions were not allowed to contain objects with non-trivial constructors or destructors.

A union containing members that are not trivially constructible must provide an explicit contructor. But there's no way to spell out a constructor for an anonymous union. What do Vector and Point look like? Can you show a [mcve]?

@RemyLebeau Yes, when I give them names it seems to get past that issue... but then it gives me a thousand other issues because vertex.mColor has to become vertex.mUnion.mColor

@ChrisDodd I am using gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0,  with this in my CMakeLists: set_target_properties(CTest PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17 CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON CXX_EXTENSIONS ON)

@IgorTandetnik Both Point and Vector have Point() {} and Vector() {} constructors, which I thought were providing the trivial constructor needed.  I don't have a small repro because I'm porting a whole code framework over to linux, but simply trying to compile the class pasted above along with class Point() {Point() {};float mX;float mY;} (and adding mZ for vector) reproduces the problem for me with a single C++ file.

A user-defined constructor, even empty, is not a trivial constructor. Your example compiles if I don't provide a constructor at all, or make it Point() = default;, but not if I make it Point() {}

Though oddly, adding a constructor to Vector still works. The compiler doesn't mind such member in a top-level union, but only when it's nested deeper. I must admit I don't know why. I would have expected it to complain either way.

@IgorTandetnik • it worked for me too, until I accessed any of the uninitialized fields.  At which point the sanitizer got grumpy.  If I initialize things, it's all good.  I did have to make the code valid C++ by adding names to things.

Point(){} doesn't initialize fields either.

@IgorTandetnik Ah, good catch.  Well this sucks!  Those unions were only for convenience (i.e. to  access the UV of the vertex simply, or to use the Point version to access a lot of helper methods).  I'll have to see in what way I can get around this.

It looks like you intend to assign one union member and read from another ("for convenience") but this is Undefined Behavior in C++.

@Eugene There's some dispensation for a union whose members are standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence; in which case you can read those common members through either struct. I think the OP's code might skate on that.

Posting this for posterity: There's no solution for this using gcc up to 11.4.0 (might be fixed in the future; since the complaint only arises if you nest unions, it seems like a bug)... but clang 14.0.0 handles it without any issues, so I've switched over to compiling with clang.
